# Socket.io using the name "in" makes Webstorm IDE raise error

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webstorm

I am using socket.io 8.7. I use Webstorm as IDE for writing my network app.

Webstorm shows me an error when I write this:

```
io.sockets.in("some room id").emit(...)
```

Webstorm underlines the `in` with red and says "name expected". The result in Webstorm showing the entire JavaScript file containing this code line as a broken code file.

Does anyone know how to tell Webstorm to ignore this error? It is very annoying as it covers real error messages.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because "in" is a reserved word in JavaScript. It's an operator:

```
if ("someString" in someObject) {
  // someObject has a property called "someString"
}
```

In other words, that *is* a "real error".  Now, you can do this if you really really want a property/method called "in":

```
io.sockets['in']("some room id").emit(...)
```

Comment: I guess io.sockets['in']... would do for now. Then Webstorm won't complain and I can still use the functionality in socket.io. Would have been nice, if socket.io didn't rely on reserved words in the first place, but thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 3):

Send a bug report to their [tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/dashboard/WI#tab=0&newissue=yes)

**Edit**: No, this is **not a bug** with socket.io. There's nothing wrong with using reserved words as object keys in JavaScript - reserved words are only reserved as **identifiers** (a variable/function name), not anywhere else. This is a bug with WebStorm IDE, probably because it is common to not allow reserved words at all in other languages (which there's no reason to do, really).

References:

- [ES5 specifications 7.6.1](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1)

  > A reserved word is an IdentifierName that *cannot be used as an Identifier*
- [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#Reserved_word_usage)

  > Reserved Words actually *only apply to Identifiers*

Comment: I think a better solution would be to send the report to the socket.io creator :)

Comment: If you try it in Internet Explorer 8 or older, you'll see that it's treated as an error.

Comment: ... that said, whether Internet Explorer 8 or older is relevant to socket.io is a fair point :-)  The IDE however probably doesn't (and really can't) know whether some code may be intended to support Internet Explorer, and it's a good guess of course that it will.

Comment: socket.io does have fallbacks for older browsers, so it is relevant for IE. However, I would expect an IDE to work according to the language specifications, not according to weird browsers quirks.